# how to display and image using external jquery in my html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to jquery, can anyone tell me how to display and image using external jquery in my html file.

i want my html to be clean and load the image where the image path is mentioned in the external jquery file.

my jquery file will be like this testjquery.js

```
 // url to load the image (which i dont know ,whats the code for it)
```

and in my html file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var test = document.createElement('script');
            test.type = 'text/javascript'; 
            test.async = true;
            test.src = 'testquery.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(test, s);

            test.onload=function(){
                // function to load the external image
            }
         })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by external jquery?
you mean embedding jQuery from  google for example?

Comment: Please take time to phrase a proper question so we don't have to guess what you are asking.

Comment: Please ask your question in advanced and not change the whole thing after you already have 3 answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

**HTML**

```
<div id="divWhereYouWantAddImage"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#divWhereYouWantAddImage').append("<img src='img.jpg' />");
```

You can read more about jquery `.append()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you mean... but i guess you mean obtrusive jQuery. So your html stays clean. The javascript you can put it in an external file or at the bottom of your page. If you put it in an external file you can delete the script tags.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="style.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="image"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in style.js (you can put it in the same directory)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    imagePath = 'your_image.png';
    $('#image').html("<img src='" + imagePath + "' />")
  });
```

You can use html or append. The html function clears the whole image div and replaces it with the image. The append, appends it to the div so you can add another one later. The (document).ready function will run after the whole document is loaded.

Comment: yes, i want my html to be clean and load the image where the image path is mentioned in the external jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

i think your question is wrong
so test this

first sure Loaded Jquery script file

and Set html for div Element

```
<div id="imageContainer"></div>

<script>
    $('#imageContainer').html('<img src="/images/test.jpg" />');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the file content in ExternalJSFile.js

```
imageUrl = 'your/img/path.png';
```

Your html file

```
<html>  
</html>

<script src="ExternalJSFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     alert(imageUrl);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: imageUrl = 'your/img/path.png'; is not storing the image and its not displaying anything. please help